# MSDeploy -setParam option is replacing `"&quot;"` with` "&amp;quot"` in the connection string

Tags: cmd, msdeploy, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy, webdeploy-3.6

When deploying app with msdeploy, i am changing connection string with option -setparam, this is changing connection string but replacing `&quot;` with `&amp;quot;`

i have tried using `"^"` , it didn't work, if i use `"^&quot;"` i am getting `"^&amp;quot;"`

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msDeploy.exe"  -verb:sync -source:package="package.zip" -dest:auto -setParamFile="SetParameters.xml" -setParam:name="IIS Web Application Name",value="VALUE" -setParam:name="XXXX-Web.config Connection String",value="metadata=res://*/XXXXXXX|res://*/XXXXXXXX|res://*/XXXXXXXXX;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=XXXXXXX;initial catalog=XXXXX;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=false;Trusted_Connection=Yes;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
```

`"&quot;"` at end and in middle is getting replaced with `"&amp;quot;"`

Comment: Why aren't you replacing `"` with `&amp:quot;`?

Comment: That is disrupting connection to DB, i don't why it is appending "&amp" to "&", its basically making  &quot: to &amp;quot:

Answer (score 1):

MS deploy -setParam option will replace `"&quot;"`  with `"&amp;&quot"` in the connection strings, to counter that i had to replace `"&quot;"` with single quotes `'` in the connection string